# HTML button not selecting correct form value

Tags: php, html

HTML button not selecting correct form value.
The following code selects data and displays it correctly in a html table: fname, lname , customer_id and the last column in the table shows a button labelled more info.
The first part of the code works fine.

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th>Customer ID</th><th>Info</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
         <?php 
         $sql = "select fname, lname,customer_id from customer_address ";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $fname = $row['fname'];
            $lname = $row['lname'];
            $customer_id = $row['customer_id'];
            
         echo" <tr>";
          echo"<td>$fname</td>";
          echo"<td>$lname</td>";
          echo"<td>$customer_id</td>";
          echo"<td><input type='hidden' name='customer_id' value='$customer_id'>";
          echo "<button type='submit' name='submit'>More Info</button></td>" ; 
          }
          echo" </tr>";
                ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

With the second part of the code, I want to grab the customer_id when the button is clicked and display it below the table(I am going to uses the variable in a subsequent query to display more information later). The button selects the same customer_id no matter which button is clicked, and it is always the last record in the table. I would appreciate any help in correcting my error.

```
<?php
$ccf=" ";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $ccf = $_POST['customer_id'];
}
echo "Customer Id selected is:$ccf";
?>
```

Comment: These seem to be _all_ in a _single_ form, so there are multiple elements with `name='customer_id'`. Place each row inside its own form

Comment: Done, glad it works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your elements are all inside *one* form, so there are multiple elements with `name='customer_id'`. Place each row inside their own separate `<form></form>`:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th>Customer ID</th><th>Info</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
         <?php 
         $sql = "select fname, lname,customer_id from customer_address";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $fname = $row['fname'];
            $lname = $row['lname'];
            $customer_id = $row['customer_id'];
            
            echo" <tr>";
            echo "<td>$fname</td>";
            echo "<td>$lname</td>";
            echo "<td>$customer_id</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='customer_id' value='$customer_id'>";
            echo "<button type='submit' name='submit'>More Info</button>";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "</td>"; 
            echo" </tr>";
          }
          ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```